# How to get Youtube channel's email using using Python, Javascript or an API

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

Does Youtube provides any API to get channel emails using Oauth?

Or How can I get the email in About Section in the provided image using scraping with Python.

[About section Youtube email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8yqZ.png)

Comment: scraping is against googles TOS you will need to go though the official api.

Answer (score 0):

Going though the YouTube api if you use the [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22UCyqzvMN8newXIxyYIkFzPvA%22%5D%7D) method.  with the snippit

As follows

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.channels.list
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.channels().list(
        part="snippet",
        id="CHANNELID"
)
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can then see the description of the channel in the results. If the owner of the channel included the email address there then you will see it.  The description is shown in the about tab of the channel

Comment: This good so far, but is there a way to get the email which in Details section for bussiness which requiers a captcha. Thanks.

Comment: probably not this is the only way i have found so far.  This api is a little limited.